# Importing data with parenthesis and strings r

Tags: r

**EDIT: Fixed!**

I'm trying to import two columns of data from an .xy file (text file) which looks like this:

```
(title "RMSE Velocity Magnitude")
(labels "Position" "RMSE Velocity Magnitude")

((xy/key/label "rake-9")
-12 3.52859
-11.985 3.53129
-11.97  3.534
-11.955 3.5367
-11.9399    3.5394
-11.9249    3.5421
-11.9099    3.5448
-11.8949    3.54751
-11.8799    3.55021
-11.8649    3.55291
-11.8499    3.55561
-11.8348    3.55831
)
```

I'd like to skip the first 5 lines and import the data WITHOUT the parenthesis at the bottom. The latter is causing me some headaches.

So far I have the following:

```
strs <- readLines("file.xy")
dat <- read.table(text=strs,          # read from an R object rather than a file
                skip=5,               # skip the first line
                nrows=length(strs)  - 6  # skip the last line
)
```

Comment: Assuming `n` rows... you are skipping 5 rows, but asking it to read n rows. Shouldn't you ask it to read something less than or equal to n-5 rows?

Comment: Either post your "fix" as an answer or delete this question. That would be preferable to leaving this question open.

Comment: why not `read.table(text=tail(head(strs, -1), -5))` or your other favorite subsetting method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could strip the ending parenthesis from the string then read it.

```
strs  <- 
'(title "RMSE Velocity Magnitude")
(labels "Position" "RMSE Velocity Magnitude")

((xy/key/label "rake-9")
-12 3.52859
-11.985 3.53129
-11.97  3.534
-11.955 3.5367
-11.9399    3.5394
-11.9249    3.5421
-11.9099    3.5448
-11.8949    3.54751
-11.8799    3.55021
-11.8649    3.55291
-11.8499    3.55561
-11.8348    3.55831
)'

strs  <- gsub("\n)","",strs)
dat <- read.table(text=strs, skip=4)
```

NB there are 4, not 5, header lines to skip so I used a skip=4 in this example.